# Combine `MultiplexerTransform` and `ServersideOutput` transforms in `Dash` extensions

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I had trouble getting the `ServersideOutput` transform from the `dash_extensions` (https://pypi.org/project/dash-extensions/) working although the MMW example from the documentation worked fine. Now, I think, the only difference between my app and the MWE is that I use the target output multiple times (by using the `MultiplexerTransform`). Do these two transforms work in conjunction or can this be the reason, why I don't get the `ServersideOutput` working?

Comment: Could you add a minimal runnable example that demonstrates the issue that you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct. The `MultiplexerTransform` only works for normal `Output` objects, not `ServersideOutput` objects.

Comment: Is there some way to circumvent this? Combining these two transforms would be amazing...